# Need a Unity indicator for Gnome Phone Manager

Tags: unity, software-recommendation, indicator

I really want to use Gnome phone manager on Unity, but it's icon is not appearing at the top panel, like in Gnome. So I cannot use the app. Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-re-enable-notification-area.html

It works on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: One essential thing... use "gnome-phone-manager" as the key which to whitelist in the Unity panel.